# Pop up label title

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to change the title on my pop-up message in asp.net?
here is the code of the message:

```
Private Sub MessageBox(ByVal msg As String)
Dim lbl As New Label

lbl.Text = "<script language='javascript'>" & Environment.NewLine &
   "window.alert('" + msg + "');</script>"

Page.Controls.Add(lbl)

End Sub
```

But this pop-up message always shows the same title ("web page message") or in my language ("Mensagem da página web"). So the question is: is there a way to change this?

Here is a picture of the message pop-up

[image]

Comment: so it is not possible?

Comment: Not directly. See the duplicate link for alternatives - for example jQuery-UI modal dialog